# nested object becoming undefined when trying to acces its properties

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I am a newbie to web development, I'm using React and I really don't understand this error : 
I have an object "candidate" with nested inside an object "github", and I want to display the number of repos. So I tried console.log(candidate.github.repos), but it's throwing me an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'repos' of undefined". **But console.log(candidate.github) is working** and showing me my object ! This is what I got in the console :

```
Github {stars: 0, watchers: 0, forks: 0, issues: 0, size: 0, …}
stars: 0
watchers: 0
forks: 0
issues: 0
size: 0
network: 0
repos: 5
subscribers: 0
_id: "5e859c9876036d0cf33ab457"
candidate: "5df21c4417622d00137f5702"
date: "2020-04-04T10:53:19.894Z"
__proto__: Object
```

This is the candidate object I'm sending after fetching the data from the db :

```
const github = await GitHub.findOne({candidate: cand._id.toString()});    
const candidateRes = {
        concrete_experience: cand.concrete_experience,
        chronological_experience: Array.from(cand.chronological_experience),
        github
      };
      res.json(candidateRes);
```

and console.log(typeof(candidate.github)) sending back "Object"...

I'm sorry if it's a stupid mistake but I'm lost here... What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: where and how are you using in React?

Comment: on which lifecycle method you are calling backend api to fetch data?

Answer (score 0):

I understood my stupid mistake. I forgot to put the github object in the initialState of the candidate object in the reducers so it was null before the fetch had time to give me the data... But thanks for responding to me guys!